# Displaying XML Contents in a table with php

Tags: php, html, xml

I am trying to have the contents of this XML located at http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=W1AW (I'm using the W1AW call sign as an example) displayed in a table (not every entry, only "licName", "callsign", "serviceDesc", "statusDesc", and "expiredDate".)

On my website I want the use to be able to choose what call sign to search based on the url parremeter ?callsign=choicehere (ex: mywebsite.com/callsignresults.php?callsign=w1aw)

I currently have the following code. I only got the parameter working.

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=' . ($_GET["callsign"]));
echo $file;
?>
```

So how do I go about converting the XML data into a user friendly readable table.

Table Example Idea:

```
| NAME     | CALL SIGN | TYPE    | STATUS  | EXPIRATION DATE |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| John Doe | XXXX      | Amature | Active  |          1/1/13 |
| Jane Doe | X1X1X     | Amature | Expired |          1/1/13 |
```

[API Documentation](https://www.fcc.gov/developers/license-view-api)

Comment: Whats inside callsign ?

Comment: Which part are you stuck at? To read(parse) XML you can use [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: I'm stuck at parsing the data from XML. I'm not very good with XML

Comment: Good question! :-) Don't know why people would think it isn't....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Building on Neta Meta's answer:

I was having some trouble actually iterating through the XML object that was built until I realized that the XML returned is inconsistent in its capitalization. Here's some working code to parse that file into a table:

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue='.$_GET["callsign"], 0, TRUE);
?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Call Sign</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Expiration Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php foreach ($xml->Licenses->License as $licenseElement) :?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $licenseElement->licName; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $licenseElement->callsign; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $licenseElement->serviceDesc; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $licenseElement->statusDesc; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $licenseElement->expiredDate; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You, This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 4):

Well basically you can use  [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)  :

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon+Wireless');
$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($file);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($movies);
echo '<pre>';
```

And iterate through the the object you get to display the page.